# Ignore text values in subtotal function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

**Excel-Sheet:**

```
      A            B            C            D             E
1                1.200
2  Product A      500 
3  Product B      400
4  Product C      OK
5  Product D      #NA
6  Product E      300
7
8
```

---

In the above table I have list of products in `Column A` and some data about the products in `Column B`.

In `Cell B1` I want to calculated the subtotal of `Column B` using `=SUBTOTAL(9,B2:B6)`.

However, now I have the issue that `Column B` not only consists of `numbers`. 
It can also have the data type `text` (`OK, NA`). Therefore, the result in `Cell B1` currently is `#NA`.

Is there any kind of formula that I could use so only the `number data` is considered and the result is `1.200` as in the table above?

---

**Please note:** 
This function `=AGGREGATE(9,6,B2:B6)` won't help me because I want to filter the list later on so I need to go with the `SUBTOTAL`.

Comment: Both `=SUBTOTAL(9,B2:B6)` and `=SUBTOTAL(109,B2:B6)` work fine for me ignoring text.

Comment: Do you mean you have actual errors in those cells?

Comment: I put this function in those cells =NA()

Comment: Well then the easiest for you is to add `IFERROR` in your formulas in column B. And if there is an error return some text which then works fine with `SUBTOTAL`

Comment: @Michi what jvdV has advised to do in his latest comment is what i suggest as an answer, i have tested it with you data set and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `7` as the second criterion in AGGREGATE instead of `6` as it will also exclude hidden rows:

```
=AGGREGATE(9,7,B2:B6)
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this, combining the Excel worksheet functions `=Value()` and `=IfERROR()`:

The function `=Value()` gives the value of a number, and in case of text it gives an error.
`=IfError()` can be used to give 0 in that case.

So, imagine you have following situation:

```
Column A    Column B         Column C
       1  =Value(A1)   =IfError(B1;0) 
     3.5  =Value(A2)   =IfError(B2;0)
      AB  =Value(A3)   =IfError(B3;0)
   abc10  =Value(A4)   =IfError(B4;0)
```

This gives following results:

```
 Column A    Column B    Column C
        1           1           1
      3.5         3.5         3.5
       AB      #Value           0
    abc10      #Value           0
```

You can simply take the sum of column C.

Answer (score 0):

So this is based on the summary in B1.

=SUM(IF(ISERROR(B2:B6),"",B2:B6))

You need to push `Ctrl+Shft+Enter` for this to work.

Hope it helps.